# Is it possible to have a Cloudwatch alarm of the specific events of a ElastiCache Redis cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-elasticache

I need some solution to get cloudwatch alarm notification for specific elasticache events like '''ElastiCache:CacheNodeReplaceStarted''', '''ElastiCache:RemoveCacheNodeComplete'''.

I know we can enable notification to Topic, but we get all events notified.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out notifications that go to specified subscribers.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-filtering.html

The SNS topic will still received all notifications, but those subscribed to the SNS topic can receive a desired sub-set of those notifications.